# What is this Called?

Tags: keyboard

There is a stand to keep music sheets while playing the piano. It is also there for electronic keyboards, but it is made of plastic. What is this called?

Comment: The... music stand? Did you try a web search for "music stand" or "keyboard music stand" yet?

Comment: I searched for music stand, but I only got the notation stand, not the one for keyboards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is often called the "music stand" but the correct term is "music rack".

It is sometimes also called the "music rest" or "music desk."

On portable keyboards, the "stand" is usally the part between the instrument and the floor, not the part which holds the sheet music.